# Can somebody explain following java script

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var td = /^(?:(\w+)\.)?(?:(\w+):)?(\w+)$/
var b = td.exec("test");
alert(b);
```

The results is .... test,,,test or you can say an array of length 4 with the 1st and last elements of the array being string itself but middle two elements are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `/^(?:(\w+)\.)?(?:(\w+):)?(\w+)$/` means:

```
/           : regex delimiter
  ^         : start of string
    (?:     : start NON capture group
      (     : start capture group 1
        \w+ : 1 or more letter, digit or _
      )     : end group 1
      \.    : a dot
    )?      : end non capture group, optional
    (?:     : start NON capture group
      (     : start capture group 2
        \w+ : 1 or more letter, digit or _
      )     : end group 2
      :     : column
    )?      : end non capture group, optional
    (       : start capture group 3
      \w+   : 1 or more letter, digit or _
    )       : end group 3
  $         : end of string
/           : regex delimiter
```

You can see you have 3 capture groups.

With the word `test`, the first group is empty because you don't have a dot after `test`; the second group is also empty because you don't have `:` after `test`; only the third group contains `test`.

The result of `var b = td.exec("test");` is an array where, in first element `b[0]` you'll find the whole match (ie. `test`), then `b[1]` and `b[2]` contains respectivly the first and the second group that are empty; `b[3]` contains the third group that is `test`.

That's why your resulting array is

```
['test', '', '', 'test']
 |       |   |   third group
 |       |   second group
 |       first group
 whole match
```

Comment: Thank you @Toto. I was clear with the expressions but not the capturing part

Comment: @: It is what seemed to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a regex (regular expression). They can be quite messy and hard to read. You can add your regex in https://regex101.com/ to translate it to human readable. This will give you an idea of what its doing.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript exec() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp)

[JavaScript RegExp Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

The \w+ searches for a Word so "test" will be found. 
exec() puts all what it founds in an array.
That's all i can see from it.

Answer (score 0):

@Simple, its not that simple regex (`/^(?:(\w+)\.)?(?:(\w+):)?(\w+)$/`)

> `?:` => non-capturing regex group

Let me break it for you:
`/^(?:(\w+)\.)?(?:(\w+):)?(\w+)$/`

- `^` start of the string
- `(?:(\w+)\.)?`

  - Optional(`:?`)
  - At-least one word (`\w+`) - only it would be captured
  - That word should end with dot(`\.`)
  - Non capturing (ending with `?`)
- `(?:(\w+):)?`

  - Optional(`:?`)
  - At-least one word (`\w+`) - only it would be captured
  - That word should end with dot(`:`)
  - Non capturing (ending with `?`)
- `(\w+)`

  - At-least one word (`\w+`) - it would be captured
- `$`

  - End of the test string

Here, let me show you how `test` would execute for some quick sample strings:

1. `"lorem.ipusm:red"`
   Match: `lorem.ipusm:red`
   Groups: `[lorem, ipsum, red]`
2. `"ipusm:red"`
   Match: `ipusm:red`
   Groups: `[ipsum, red]`
3. `"red`
   Match: `red`
   Groups: `[red]`

> `"` is not part of the string above. Its just for representing the
>   string

Comment: This is not correct. `(?:pattern)` is a non-capturing group, not making something optional. `?` after a pattern is the zero or one quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

You have regex with three parts-

- `(?:(\w+)\.)?` - It's mean zero or more word characters and `.` (For  example `e_123.`). All this part can be zero or one time.
- `(?:(\w+)\.)?` - Like the first.
- `(\w+)` - It's mean zero or more word characters.

Just the first part match any charctar of the string.

Exec function return an array. The first is the match text and the others is the capturing groups.

So you have the match string "test", two capturing groups with empty string and the last matching group "test.

The result is - `["test", undefined, undefined, "test"]`.

(I'm sorry about my english...)